# How do I turn on my tablet?

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, tablet

I have a Samsung SM-T110 (android tablet) and I was having WiFi problems so I decided to Factory Reset it. **It shutdown and it booted into some different place where I wiped something** (I wanted to wipe everything, so I probably did). Then **I rebooted it into the bootloader and now it doesn't start**. Maybe I deleted the OS too? I doubt it but I don't know... This is my problem right now but I know the WiFi problems will come back, so I need help.

I don't know what happened for it to stay that way. I was able to connect to the WiFi but the connection would be so slow that I couldn't do anything. An average image would take like 3 minutes to download. I had about 5 updates in the play store that never downloaded because it took too long. For some reason my tablet has always had problems with the play store... I have to uninstall its update or else it doesn't work or drains all the battery in 1 or 2 hours, but then it installs it again...

**What do I do about the tablet not turning on? How do I solve the Play store issues forever?**

Thank you.

Comment: When you're in download mode(bootloader), go to your pc and download a firmware from here: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-T110/ On the site of the firmware you are going to download are instructions at the bottom of the site. Follow these and your tablet gets back to life pretty quickly

Comment: @benjaminS Thank you. This will take forever to download... I just need the firmware inside the zip, do you know where I can get it? I couldn't find it on Samsung's website...

Comment: I started the download now, when I am finished I can provide a high speed mirror for you on my google drive if you'd like, I'll comment again when it is ready ;)

Comment: Damn! That would be awesome! :D Don't forget to reply to the post so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jpOfxfWhoUSktwVkRfY1lkVHM/view?usp=sharing 
here you go man - tell me if it works for you, if you have further question you can ask anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're in download mode(bootloader), go to your pc and download a firmware from here: [sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-T110](http://sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-T110)

Follow the instructions on the site:

```
Extract (unzip) the firmware file
Download Odin v3.10.7
Extract Odin ZIP file
Open Odin v3.10.7
Reboot Phone in Download Mode (press and hold Home + Power + Volume Down buttons)
Connect phone and wait until you get a blue sign in Odin
Add the firmware file to AP / PDA
Make sure re-partition is NOT ticked
Click the start button, sit back and wait few minutes
```

Comment: Thank you very much, everything worked perfectly! (No wifi issues yet)

Comment: Do you still face problems with the PlayStore or is it working better now?

Comment: I don't want to update it, that was my mistake the last time. For now everything is nice, ty. :)